# Laravel 5.4 - Regex with request_if validation

Tags: php, laravel

In my project, the users who have email ends with @gmail.com, need to apply user agreement.

I've tried this:

```
'agree' => 'required_if,regex:/(.*)gmail\.com$/i',
```

I also tried this:

```
'agree' => [
'required_if:email,regex:/(.*)santafarma\.com\.tr$/i'
]
```

Both of this not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Rules are seperated using the pipe `|` symbol.

Try `'agree' => 'required_if:email|regex:/(.*)@gmail\.com$/i'`.

You cannot use the `regex` rule as a parameter of `required_if` see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-if

Comment: You Don't have @ in your expression @Alex

Comment: @bluemoon It wasn't in the OP's regex but it's probably a good idea to add that to only match `example@gmail.com` and not also `example@fakegmail.com`.

Answer (score 0):

`'agree' => [Rule::requiredIf(preg_match('/(.*)gmail\.com$/i', $this->email), 'bool']`

in larevel 9 Rule::requiredIf() accept bool

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-required-if